# Leaflet onEachFeature not working; related to Ajax call?

Tags: ajax, leaflet

I'm fairly new to Javascript and Leaflet, so apologies if I'm missing something obvious here, but...

I'm trying to use Leaflet to overlay a series of lines and points on a map, and I want to open a sidebar whenever the user clicks on one of those lines or points. Since the content of the sidebar will vary depending on which line or point the user clicks, I'm trying to use onEachFeature for the mouse event, since I'll then be able to display information related to the appropriate feature.

The problem, though, is that onEachFeature never seems to be called. Here's my code:

```
    function sortAndVisualizeNetwork(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "d3/networkdata.json", 
            async: false, 
            dataType: "json", 
            success: function(data){ 
                edges = L.geoJson(data, {
                    filter: function(feature){
                        if (includeFeature(feature)){
                            visualizeFeature(feature);
                        }
                    },
                    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
                        layer.on("click", function(e){
                            //write stuff to sidebar depending on the feature
                            sidebar.show();   
                        });
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

I've tried replacing the layer.on code with simple alerts, none of which appear, so I know onEachFeature isn't being called. The functions within filter work just fine, though.

I'm wondering if this is related to the fact that this is all nested within a synchronous ajax call?

Comment: can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code, so it'd be helpful to identify the issue

Comment: Hey Muzaffar my issue is also related to this question. can u answer to this my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73432932/api-is-not-working-inside-oneachfeature-react-leaflet-function . i also put the codesandbox link too in my post